Find Notes returning notes that don’t match filter when filtering on folder
I’m trying to find all notes in a folder that have a specific string in the body. I have this step but it’s returning notes that don’t match.
In the screenshot below, the word Imgur is not anywhere in the body.
This only happens when I have the folder filter? If I remove the folder filter, it works as expected.
Does anyone know what’s wrong? Is it a bug?

